Show that $E[X] = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha +\beta}$ for the beta probability distribution function
Show that $E[X] = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha +\beta}$
Let X be a continuous random variable we say that  $ X ∼ Beta(α, β);\alpha,\beta >0 $ if his density function is:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)} x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$$
I was trying:
$$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x( \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)} x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1})$$
$$E[X] = \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  x^{\alpha}(1-x)^{\beta-1})$$
$$E[X] = \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\frac{T(\alpha+1) T(\beta)}{T(\alpha+ \beta +1)}$$
$$E[X] = \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)} \frac{\alpha T(\alpha) T(\beta)}{(\alpha+ \beta)T(\alpha+ \beta)}$$
$$E[X] = \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+ \beta}$$
Where T is the Gamma function
but I failed

I am not sure about $T(a+b) = T(a)T(b)$ is that valid?

For all $k \ge 0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb {E} \left[ {X}^{k} \right]
& = \int_{0}^{1} {x}^{k} \cdot \frac {1}{\text {B} \left( \alpha, \beta \right)} {x}^{\alpha - 1} {\left( 1 - x \right)}^{\beta - 1} \text {d} x \\
& = \frac {1}{\text {B} \left( \alpha, \beta \right)} \cdot \int_{0}^{1} {x}^{\alpha + k - 1} {\left( 1 - x \right)}^{\beta - 1} \text {d} x \\
& = \frac {1}{\text {B} \left( \alpha, \beta \right)} \cdot \text {B} \left( \alpha + k, \beta \right) \\
& = \frac {\Gamma \left( \alpha + \beta \right)}{\Gamma \left( \alpha \right) \Gamma \left( \beta \right)} \cdot \frac {\Gamma \left( \alpha + k \right) \Gamma \left( \beta \right)}{\Gamma \left( \alpha + \beta + k \right)} \\
& = \frac {\Gamma \left( \alpha + k \right)}{\Gamma \left( \alpha \right)} \, \bigg/ \, \frac {\Gamma \left( \alpha + \beta + k \right)}{\Gamma \left( \alpha + \beta \right)} = \boxed {\frac {{\alpha}^{\left( k \right)}}{{\left( \alpha + \beta \right)}^{\left( k \right)}}}.
\end{align}
$$
For instance,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb {E} \left[ {X}^{0} \right]
& = 1, \\
\mathbb {E} \left[ {X}^{1} \right]
& = \frac {\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}, \\
\mathbb {E} \left[ {X}^{2} \right]
& = \frac {\alpha \left( \alpha + 1 \right)}{\left( \alpha + \beta \right) \left( \alpha + \beta + 1 \right)}, \\
\mathbb {E} \left[ {X}^{3} \right]
& = \frac {\alpha \left( \alpha + 1 \right) \left( \alpha + 2 \right)}{\left( \alpha + \beta \right) \left( \alpha + \beta + 1 \right) \left( \alpha + \beta + 2 \right)}, \\
\mathbb {E} \left[ {X}^{4} \right]
& = \frac {\alpha \left( \alpha + 1 \right) \left( \alpha + 2 \right) \left( \alpha + 3 \right)}{\left( \alpha + \beta \right) \left( \alpha + \beta + 1 \right) \left( \alpha + \beta + 2 \right) \left( \alpha + \beta + 3 \right)}.
\end{align}
$$
I hope this helps.
